# Is there a way to make a the camera orbit around a GameObject while updating rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to code a car in Unity 5 which can move like a normal car but have the camera orbit around it. I have this working but the camera does not keep it's orbit position when the car turns. Example: I'm looking at the back of the car, and I turn right. I will now be looking at the right side of the car. Is there any way to make the camera still be in the same position, relative to the car.

I got the car movement from this tutorial, but I didn't like the camera movement in it, I wanted the camera to orbit the car. I followed this one for the camera movement. However, I am trying to modify it so the camera turns with the car and doesn't reset to the back of the car

CameraManager.cs:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputManager im;
    public bool lockCursor;
    public float distance = 5f;
    public float mouseSensitivity = 10f;
    public Transform target;
    public Vector2 pitchMinMax = new Vector2 (-40, 85);
    public float rotationSmoothTime = 0.12f;

    Vector3 rotationSmoothVelocity;
    Vector3 currentRotation;
    float yaw;
    float pitch;

    void Start()
    {
        im = GetComponent<InputManager>();
        if (lockCursor)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {

        yaw += (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")) * mouseSensitivity;
        pitch -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;
        pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, pitchMinMax.x, pitchMinMax.y);

        currentRotation = Vector3.SmoothDamp(currentRotation, new Vector3(pitch, yaw), ref rotationSmoothVelocity, rotationSmoothTime);
        transform.eulerAngles = currentRotation;

        print(target.transform.forward);
        transform.position = target.position - transform.forward * distance;

    }
}
```

InputManager.cs:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float throttle;
    public float steer;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        throttle = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        steer = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        print(steer);
    }
}
```

CarController.cs:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


[RequireComponent(typeof(InputManager))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class CarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputManager im;
    public List<WheelCollider> throttleWheels;
    public List<WheelCollider> steeringWheels;
    public float strengthCo = 10000f; //Strength Coefficent
    public float maxTurn = 20f;
    public Transform CM;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        im = GetComponent<InputManager>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        if (CM)
        {
            rb.centerOfMass = CM.position;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        foreach (WheelCollider wheel in throttleWheels)
        {
            wheel.motorTorque = strengthCo * Time.deltaTime * im.throttle;
        }
        foreach (WheelCollider wheel in steeringWheels)
        {
            wheel.steerAngle = maxTurn * im.steer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to do this in code. Make a GameObject that is a child of the car and place it where you want the rotation to happen. Child a camera to that GameObject pointed at the car and move it out as far as you want. Rotate the GameObject. The camera will continue to point at the car as it orbits the car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  `Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation)` as a relative rotation to apply to `target.rotation`, and apply it with `target.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation)`:

```
void LateUpdate()
{

    yaw += (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")) * mouseSensitivity;
    pitch -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;
    pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, pitchMinMax.x, pitchMinMax.y);

    currentRotation = Vector3.SmoothDamp(currentRotation, new Vector3(pitch, yaw), ref rotationSmoothVelocity, rotationSmoothTime);
    transform.rotation = target.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);

    print(target.transform.forward);
    transform.position = target.position - transform.forward * distance;

}
```